# Why does the real identity of the Joker matter?

Tags: dc, batman, the-joker

**Heavy spoilers for Justice League #50.**

> In Justice League #50, we learn the the Joker is actually 3 dudes.
>  [image: green lanter and batman discuss]

**Why does the real identity of the Joker matter ? If Batman knew it, would it be more effective at stopping him ?**

Comment: Yes. He could track his old haunts, family he might still be in contact with, subscriptions (magazines, etc) that he might still be paying for, etc etc

Comment: @Valorum - if that was a trackable pattern, shouldn't it have shown up by now?  I thought that was the whole point of Joker-style chaos, that none of those techniques ever revealed anything usable... or *normal*.

Comment: If, as Valorum suggested, you learn more about his background then there is much chance of understanding what drives him.

Comment: "If you know the enemy and know yourself, you need not fear the result of a hundred battles. If you know yourself but not the enemy, for every victory gained you will also suffer a defeat. If you know neither the enemy nor yourself, you will succumb in every battle." Supposedly Sun Tzu.

Comment: Am I the only one who understood that as him having three names?

Comment: @Davor - The implication is that he's actually three different individuals.

Comment: @Valorum - yes, I see that's how everyone is interpreting it, but I'm saying that to me it isn't that clear cut. "What is that dudes name? - There are 3" sounds more like "that dude has multiple identities". At least, to me. I see how it can be interpreted to mean that there are 3 people being Joker, but just from that one panel, it doesn't seem to be straight forward to me.

Comment: @Davor - This panel is a lot clearer; http://i.stack.imgur.com/zODvw.jpg

Answer (score 23):

### It matters because it matters to Batman

Knowing who the Joker really is has the potential to provide these advantages:

- Knowing where he grew up, where he worked or went to school, or who his acquaintances were could help Batman or the police track him when he's missing.
- The Joker may have a sensitive spot for certain family members or loved ones. This could be used against him (similar to Mr. Freeze's sensitivity toward his wife Nora).
- Any information gathered about what experiences led the Joker to become the Joker can be used to better understand his motivations and in turn predict/prevent criminal actions before they happen.
- As David Starkey mentions in the comments, Batman has been portrayed several times trying to get the Joker help instead of allowing the conflict to escalate until one of them dies. Understanding his background could provide essential insight into how to provide the psychiatric help he needs.

### It matters because it matters to readers

The Joker is Batman's greatest enemy and the one we know the least about. The idea of getting the chance to flesh out a character that has been around since 1940 has the potential to be very interesting.

People latch on to characters they love, craving as much knowledge/understanding about those characters as they can. They want new stories, new character wrinkles, and new reasons to fall in love with the characters all over again. This is the nature of storytelling.

Plus:

> Learning that the Joker has potentially been 3 different people over time is one heck of a twist, right?

Comment: Interesting that the chair said there were three, since [at the end of the "Jerome" arc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yi-oQGyuEs) on the TV show *Gotham,* three people are shown apparently taking on Jerome/Joker's spirit.

Comment: I haven't kept up with Gotham past the first season but I'm sure the Jerome arc you're referring to is no coincidence.

Comment: I'd also add that Batman has been portrayed multiple times as trying to get the Joker help.  Batman wants to end it without one of them ending up dead.  Figuring out who the Joker is/was could give some much needed insight for how best to help him.

Comment: @DavidStarkey - Good point. I added it to the answer.

Comment: There are certain characters so shrouded in mystery and conjecture that nailing them down to a set, definitive origin would take much of that mystery away.  The Phantom Stranger is one, The Joker is another.  If we KNEW that Joker was actually once Bill Hanratty from Hob's End, then we couldn't have had the story that suggested that he MIGHT be an immortal trickster god.  

The Joker should have the same origin as The Grinch - "Now please don't ask me why; no one quite knows the reason".

Comment: @VBartilucci - I absolutely, wholeheartedly agree with you. I think DC's decision here hurts the mythos rather than helping it.